# Using Raven.js is there a way to determine when an error is successfully logged to the Sentry server?

Tags: javascript, sentry

I'm building an Ionic app and using Sentry for logging. I'm calling `Raven.captureMessage()` and I need to know when the error is successfully logged so I can remove it from the local cache.

I'm saving the errors in a local cache so I can resend them at a later time if there is a connection issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an undocumented "events" API in Raven.js that works like so:

```
document.addEventListener('ravenSuccess', function (evt) {
  console.log(evt.data); // event data
});
```

I'd recommend looking at the source code to see exactly how this works: https://github.com/getsentry/raven-js/blob/master/src/raven.js#L1011

We've also started a discussion on GitHub on re-doing the events API – your feedback would be greatly appreciated: https://github.com/getsentry/raven-js/issues/524

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks!